# Multiple group commands in ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

What I want to do is enter server A via ssh, run multiple group commands in parallel, exit and enter server B and repeat etc etc.

```
echo "Entered node21" 
ssh -T node21 << EOF 
{
{ sh run_0.sh ; sh run_216.sh ; } &
{ sh run_1.sh ; sh run_217.sh ; } &
{ sh run_2.sh ; sh run_218.sh ; } &
} &>/dev/null 2>&1 
EOF
echo "Entered node22" 
ssh -T node22 << EOF 
{
{ sh run_24.sh ; sh run_240.sh ; } &
{ sh run_25.sh ; sh run_241.sh ; } &
{ sh run_26.sh ; sh run_242.sh ; } &
} &>/dev/null 2>&1 
EOF
```

However, my script stops after entering the first server (node21) and seems to wait indefinitely.
I already wrote a similar script that works with single commands.

```
ssh -T node21 << EOF 
{
sh run_0.sh & 
sh run_1.sh & 
} &>/dev/null 2>&1 
EOF
echo "node22"
ssh -T node22 << EOF 
{
sh run_12.sh & 
sh run_13.sh & 
} &>/dev/null 2>&1 
EOF
```

This one works fine (i.e. it gets in and out of node21 and runs the commands in node22 as well) so I am puzzled as to why the script doesn't work with group commands.

Comment: are you running `slurm` or `torque` or similar on your cluster?  They have options for splitting up batch jobs across multiple nodes.

Comment: @cas I'm actually not familiar with those but I don't think so

Comment: `&> /dev/null` is the same as `> /dev/null 2> /dev/null` or `> /dev/null 2>&1`.  There's no point in using `&>` to redirect both fd 1 and 2 and then also redirect fd 2.  (IMO, best to avoid the `&>` bashism and just do `> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Depending on if it matters which scripts are run on which server, you might be able to use GNU Parallel for this.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the first curly bracket pair into parenthesis. Thanks to everyone who commented